# Is "some of Mr. Trump’s own allies fear the failure to follow through was taken by Iran as a sign of weakness" grammatical?

Tags: grammaticality

Does the following construction make sense with regard to grammar?

> Some of Mr. Trump’s own allies fear the failure to follow through was taken by Iran as a sign of weakness.

Shouldn't there be a noun phrase before *was taken* instead of the verb phrase?

Source: The fourth paragraph of [this](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/21/us/politics/trump-iran-decision.html) newspaper article.

Comment: But there ***is*** a "noun phrase". It's ***the failure to follow through*** (being the "object" of ***was taken***).

Comment: Have you tried to diagram the sentence?  How far did you get with the diagram?

Comment: I misinterpreted the sentence. I wrongly assumed 'the failure to follow through' was the object of *fear*; instead of 'the failure to follow through was taken by Iran as a sign of weakness'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a "noun phrase":

"The failure to follow through" (being the "object" of was taken).

Answer (score 0):

"Some of Mr. Trump’s own allies fear the failure to follow through was taken by Iran as a sign of weakness."

It is grammatically correct as far as I can tell, however it does not read very nicely. As I read it, I had to re-read the sentence before I fully understood what was trying to be conveyed. It would be better to write:

- Some of Mr. Trump's own allies fear that the failure to follow through was taken by Iran as a sign of weakness.
- Some of Mr Trump's own allies fear that, by failing to follow through, Iran took this as a sign of weakness.
- Some of Mr Trump's own allies fear that Iran may have interpreted the failure to follow through as a sign of weakness.